# Need to find the requests equivalent of openurl() from urllib2

Tags: encoding, urllib2, python-requests, protocol-buffers

I am currently trying to modify a script to use the requests library instead of the urllib2 library. I haven't really used it before and I am looking to do the equivalent of `urlopen("http://www.example.org").read()`, so I tried the `requests.get("http://www.example.org").text` function.

This works fine with normal everyday html, however when I fetch from this url (https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/Feed/SEQ) it doesn't seem to work.

So I wrote the below code to print out the responses from the same url using both the requests and urllib2 libraries.

```
import urllib2
import requests

#urllib2 request
request = urllib2.Request("https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/Feed/SEQ")
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)

#requests request
result2 = requests.get("https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/Feed/SEQ")
print result2.encoding

#urllib2 write to text
open("Output.txt", 'w').close()
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(result.read())
text_file.close()

open("Output2.txt", 'w').close()
text_file = open("Output2.txt", "w")
text_file.write(result2.text)
text_file.close()
```

The `openurl().read()` works fine but the `requests.get().text` doesn't work for the given this url. I suspect it has something to do with encoding, but i don't know what. Any thoughts?

Note: The supplied url is a feed in the google protocol buffer format, once I receive the message i give the feed to a google library that interprets it.

Comment: Excellent statement of the problem WITH explanatory code.  This problem has stumped me more than once, because there FOUR incompatible packages exist that overlap in functionality: Requests, urllib, urllib2, and urllib3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you're making the `requests` module interpret **binary content** in a response as **text**.

A response from the `requests` library has two main way to access the body of the response:

- **[`Response.content`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/2440b6f089f4c53e96cd2ece80e92774b72ed243/requests/models.py#L720-L742)** - will return the response body as a **bytestring**
- **[`Response.text`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/2440b6f089f4c53e96cd2ece80e92774b72ed243/requests/models.py#L744-L780)** - will decode the response body *as text* and return **unicode**

Since protocol buffers are a binary format, you should use `result2.content` in your code instead of `result2.text`.

---

**`Response.content`** will return the body of the response as-is, in **bytes**. For binary content this is exactly what you want. For text content that contains non-ASCII characters this means the content must have been encoded by the server into a bytestring using a particular encoding that is indicated by either a HTTP header or a `<meta charset="..." />` tag. In order to make sense of those bytes they therefore need to be *decoded* after receiving using that charset.

**`Response.text`** now is a convenience method that does exactly this for you. It assumes the response body is text, and looks at the response headers to find the encoding, and decodes it for you, returning **`unicode`**.

But if your response doesn't contain text, this is the wrong method to use. Binary content doesn't contain characters, because it's not text, so the whole concept of *character* encoding does not make any sense for binary content - it's only applicable to text composed of characters. (That's also why you're seeing `response.encoding == None` - it's just bytes, there is no *character* encoding involved).

See [Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) and [Binary Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) in the `requests` documentation for more details.

Comment: This is the best explanation of this I have seen anywhere !!  This should be moved into the standard documentation for `requests` and `urllib2`.  Thank you Lukas !!